# Eclipse Java 8 Error: Label cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, label

I am trying to program an 'Inch-to-Centimeter Calculator'. I've got a problem with the method umrechnen(). The label lblCenti cannot be resolved. My Code is equal to the Solutioncode. I am grateful for every answer or tip I get.

I don't know what I should add to my Description, but StackOverflow forces me to write more, so I'm writing this.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class ZollZentimeter extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField tfInch;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ZollZentimeter frame = new ZollZentimeter();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ZollZentimeter() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 359, 157);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Umrechnen");
        btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                umrechnen();
            }
        });
        btnCalculate.setBounds(12, 77, 116, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnCalculate);

        JButton btnEnde = new JButton("Ende");
        btnEnde.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnEnde.setBounds(214, 77, 116, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnEnde);

        JLabel lblZoll = new JLabel("Zoll");
        lblZoll.setBounds(12, 13, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblZoll);

        tfInch = new JTextField();
        tfInch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    umrechnen();
                }
            }
        });

        JLabel lblCenti = new JLabel("");
        lblCenti.setBounds(214, 42, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(lblCenti);
        tfInch.setBounds(12, 42, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(tfInch);
        tfInch.setColumns(10);

        }

        private void umrechnen(){
            DecimalFormat f=new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
            double z, cm;
            z=Double.parseDouble(tfInch.getText());
            cm=z*2.54;
            lblCenti.setText(f.format(cm+" cm"));
            tfInch.requestFocus();
            tfInch.selectAll();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JLabel lblCenti = new JLabel("");
```

`"lblCenti"` is defined as a `local` variable so it can only be accessible in the method/constructor where you define it.

It you want to access the label in another method you need to define it as an `instance` variable, the same way you do with the `"tfInch"` variable.